# upload file but directory doesn't exist

Tags: php, upload, directory, temporary

I'm a newbie programmer doing his best to self learn PHP.  I'm trying to get a file upload to work, and I'm having some problems.  The file seems to successfully upload, but it's temporary location is a location that doesn't exist on the server.

Here's the code I'm using to upload the file:

```
<?php       
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$imgfile = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['imgfile']['type'];

if (!empty($imgfile))
{
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME')
    or die('Error connecting to database');
    $query = "INSERT INTO photos VALUES(0, '$imgfile',NOW(), '$temp', '$type')";

        mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

        //clear the form                    
    $imgfile = "";

        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
}
?>
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "POST" action = "<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<label for = "imgfile">Filename:</label>
<input type = "file" id = "imgfile" name = "imgfile"  />
<br />
<input type = "submit" value = "upload" name = "submit" id = "submit" /> 
</form>
```

These are some examples of locations that the `$_FILES['tmp_name']` variable says it's being stored:

`/tmp/phpWw6aut`

or

`/tmp/php4bzVfE`

The default temporary directory set in the `php.ini` file is `root/tmp`.  So that part is right, but then there's that weird `/phpgarbage` folder supposedly inside the `tmp` folder that each file is saying that it's in.  Only thing is, that those folders don't exist on the server.

Any thoughts?  Let me know if there's anything I can be more specific about.  This is a first time programming related post for me, so let me know if there's any more information I should be sharing.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: its not a folder its a file name, its random allocated by php.

Comment: so the /phpblahblah is the filename of my uploaded file?  Should I still be able to see those files in the temporary folder after the upload?

Comment: yes, but they are very temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the image in order to be able to access it later. To do this, add the following code:

```
$path = "uploads/images/";
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"], $path . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]);
}
```

after the following lines:

```
if (!empty($imgfile))
{
```

Note that the `$path` must be writeable. And now the filename becomes `$path.$_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]`. Also make sure to implement some security checks, your code is vurnerable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response!  I have three follow up questions for you.  1)  should I be able to see the picture in the default temporary folder after the upload?  and  2)  Once I do the move, I should be able to see the picture in the folder I moved it to right?  and then 3)when I set the path of the folder I want the picture moved to I only need to set it starting from the directory that the php file is in correct?  So, my php file is currently in a folder called html, and I want it moved to Images, so I'd just use $path = "/Images";..is that right?  Thanks!

Comment: 1) no. 2) yes; 3) if your php file is under /www/html, and the path = "images/" (no slash at the beginning), your images will be under /www/html/images

Answer (score 1):

You need to move it from temp storage to your directory...

```
if (is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'] )) {
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'], '/path/filename.jpg' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to control where you want to store the file.
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php